# Interation over a Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I was wondering how to `Iterate` over a binary tree to receive the number of elements in it.

This is my code so far:

```
public static int Iteration(Node<Integer> node){
    if(node.getRight() != null && node.getLeft() != null)
        return Iteration(node.getRight()) + Iteration(node.getLeft()) + count++;
    else if(node.getRight() != null && node.getLeft() == null)
        return Iteration(node.getRight()) + count++;
    else if(node.getLeft() != null && node.getRight() == null)
        return Iteration(node.getLeft()) + count++;
    else
        return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public static int countElements(Node<Integer> node) {
    if(node == null) return 0;

    // Left children plus right children plus current node    
    return countElements(node.getLeft()) + countElements(node.getRight()) + 1;
}
```

You can pass a node or null, and it will return the number of nodes below the node you passed in.  If the node you passed in is `null`, it will return 0 immeditely. Otherwise it will recursively check the child nodes and return the sum.

**Edit:** As an example, let's look at the tree below:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

If you call the method with `countElements(nodeA)`, it will recursively call `countElements(B)` and `countElements(C)`.

`countElements(B)` in turn calls the method for both its children, which are both null and the method calls thus result in 0. `countElements(B)` returns `0 + 0 + 1`, which equals 1.

For `countElements(C)` it works the same way, only one level deeper -- `countElements(C)` returns 3.

`countElements(A)` now returns `1 + 3 + 1`, which equals 5 and which is also the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: It didn't work. It doesn't accumulate the number of elements and if it does, it'll return number of possibilities to reach from the root the the leaves, times 2.

Comment: I forgot a `+ 1` and just edited it in, did you try it with that?

Comment: Yep, returns the number of possibilities, times 2

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I don't see how this could possibly the outcome

Comment: What I'm searching for is, the number of actual nodes in the binary tree.
Let's take a 4 x 4 simetric binary tree. which has 4! nodes.
The code you've sent me, calculates the number of nodes from the root to the bottom. However, it repeats over certain nodes which results a number that resembles the number of possibilities to reach from the root the the bottom

Comment: Please add an example to your question. A sample tree and  your desired result. I added an explanation to my answer on how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

this is doing a pre order traversal recursively to get node count

```
public static int getNodeCount(Node<Integer> node){
    int count = 1;
    if(node.getRight() != null)
        count += getNodeCount(node.getRight());
    if(node.getLeft() != null)
        count += getNodeCount(node.getLeft());

    return count;
}
```

Comment: It returns the number of possibilities, to reach the bottom from the root, times 2. Instead of the node count.

Comment: `private Node<T> right;`

`public Node<T> getRight(){
  return this.right;
 }`